# Create Root POM for Multi Repo Multi Module project

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, module

Need some help with creating a root pom file for managing multi git repo project for a structure like below

--root 
    |-- Project A (Git Repo A) 
    |-- Project B (Git Repo B)
    |-- Project C (Git Repo C)

Can I use **multi-rooted repositories** feature in IntelliJ Idea for this?

Comment: Are those projects independent of each other? Why then a parent root ? Or do they belong together? than the question: Why are the in separate git repos?

Comment: Those projects fully independent and dependency managed through APIs. Required a root pom to manage easily for manage as one project for different modules which in different repos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you call "multi-rooted repositories" feature, but if you mean the ability to control several repositories as one (previously called Synchronous control), then yes, you can use it.

The feature can be used when:

1. There are more than one git repository in the project (and they are registered in Settings | Version control
2. They are on the same branch (branches have the same name)

For the feature to work correctly all repositories should also have the same set of branches.

If the above is true, IDE will automatically enable **Execute branches on all roots** option when the Branches popup is opened for the first time after project creation, and all branch operations like new branch creations, checkout, merge, rebase, etc will be executed on all repositories as they were a single one.
The setting can also be enabled manually in Setting | Version Control | Git